# Chi-square warning in propensity score weighting

Tags: r, ps, chi-squared, gbm

I am using the propensity score weighting `ps()` function of the `twang` package to equalise two groups of active labour market programme (ALMP) participants that differ in a number of ways. One of the differences is the level of education that for the sake of this question I recoded into two levels: one value for those with at least primary education, another for those with at most primary education.

When I include this variable as factor:

```
 ALMP$Education_f2 = factor(ALMP$Education_f2, levels = c(„at.least.primary“, „at.most.primary“), ordered = TRUE)
```

R starts complaining during iteration that `Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect`.

When I include the education variable as integer

```
ALMP$Education_int = as.integer(ALMP$Education_int)
```

R issues no warning.

Griffin et al say [here](https://www.rand.org/statistics/twang/r-tutorial.html) that the `twang` package can handle categorical variables:

> There is no need to specify interaction terms in the formula. There
>   is also no need — and it can be counterproductive — to create
>   indicator, or "dummy coded," variables to represent categorical
>   covariates, provided the categorical variables are stored as a factor
>   or as ordered (see help(factor) for more details).

If this is true, then why is R complaining? And is this something I should worry about?

I also read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81483/warning-in-r-chi-squared-approximation-may-be-incorrect/81485?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that, as a general rule, chi square complains if any categories have less than 5 observations. This is not my case, since if I run a (2x2) cross tab on education and programme type, the minimum share of participants in one subgroup is 2810 (8% of all cases).

Of course, I could just keep the education variable as integer (0/1), but I am asking this question because, if possible, I would like to refine the variable and include it with more than two levels (e.g.: no education, primary, secondary, tertiary), where obviously an integer variable will not work anymore.

I have altogether some 35 thousand observations in the data frame, and am using 3.4.2. version of R (x64) on Windows 7 Professional (x64).

The data comes from a public registry database with some confidentiality rules, so unfortunately I cannot share it, but am happy to describe any feature in more detail that can help clarify the situation.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You don't need to share your data, but you should strive to share a minimum, reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Yes, I am working on it, but would like to ask for a little patience because I need to find out how I can recreate my sample covariates with differently skewed distributions in the two groups. Thank you!

Comment: I apologise, I have been trying to recode my data set, so that I could post an anonymised version to SO, and when I rerun the `ps` function on my new df, the warning did not appear again. I do not understand what happened. (One of the differences in my old and new dfs is that the former contains a string variable with East-European diacritics – perhaps that could have caused an issue?) Anyway, all is fine now. Please let me know if I should do anything with this post. I do not want to receive a downvote. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you've sorted it out. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. I am using R Studio, and it has to do with the fact whether I write my code in a R Markdown or an R Script.

The problem only occurs when I pass a factor variable into a ps function in R Markdown, like this:

```
library(twang)
data("lalonde") 

lalonde$college = ifelse(lalonde$educ<13, 0, 1)
lalonde$college_f = factor(lalonde$college, ordered = TRUE)

ps.lalonde_f = ps(treat ~ age + college_f + black + hispan + nodegree + married + re74 + re75,
                  data = lalonde, 
                  n.tree = 1000,
                  interaction.depth = 2, 
                  shrinkage = 0.01,
                  perm.test.iters = 0,
                  stop.method = c("es.mean", "ks.max"),
                  estimand = "ATT",
                  verbose = FALSE)
```

When I replace the `college_f` argument to a numeric `college` in the ps() function, I receive no chi-square warnings anymore. Also, if I just pass the above code to an R Script, the warning does not appear either.

(I am using R-Studio version 1.1.442.)